# Get all objects on ArrayList

Tags: java, android, realm

> can some one explain me how to get all categories value from

```
"categories":[{"1":1,"2":"orange","3":"mango","4":"guava","5":5,"6":6}]
```

result my like this 1 = 1, and 2 = orange,

what must i do i am stuck in here

```
public RealmList<CategoryRealm> categories;
```

or

```
 p.categories = new RealmList<>();
```

can some one explain to me what must i do in the next method i am stuck tried searching but so damn hard to learn its diferent.

Comment: Wait, so it's a list of **objects** that have 1-based index number keys, and their type is not deterministic? The only way to parse that is manually. The backend team responsible for this API was not very good at API design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GSON library.

Create an object that matches your structure. I'm assuming you have a structure of

```
{
    "categories"://the rest of the stuff here
}


class MyParentObject{
   @SerializeName("categories")
   ArrayList<String> myList;
}
```

Then use GSON to create it

```
 MyParentObject obj = (MyParentObject)getGson().fromJson(json, classType);
```

and your done.

If the base is just the categories string then your json is badly formatted and you may have to do a subString call to get starting index of "[" and go from there into json management.